# Find table name that value is in? Mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, datatable

i have 3 tables, tfQuestions, oeQuestions, MultQuetsions, I have a specific question and i want to to see what table it is in. is there any specific query i can use to do this? If not can i search using an if else like:

```
if 

 SELECT question From tfquestion WHERE question = $question  { if true do this}

else if

 SELECT question From oequestion WHERE question = $question  { if true do this}

else if

 SELECT question From multquestion WHERE question = $question  { if true do this}
```

Comment: your approach is correct.

Comment: Use an inner `UNION` query, and the comparison on a wrapping `SELECT`.

Comment: The data modelling is questionable IMHO. Any reason you cannot put everything into a table called QUESTION and then each record has a column which denotes type (ie. multi_choice, true_false, 'whatever oe is'). Would you consider remodelling the data?

Comment: @mario The UNION query will get him the record, but it won't give him the information he seeks, which is which table the record comes from.

Comment: is there any way different to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which table which question originated from, you can just select a literal identification string with each query:

```
 SELECT 'tf' AS tbl_name, question FROM tfquestions
```

Next up join the three tables in an [`UNION`](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?group=MySQL&q=UNION) and an outer driver query:

```
SELECT tbl_name, question
FROM (
      SELECT 'tf' AS tbl_name, question FROM tfquestions
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'oe' AS tbl_name, question FROM oequestions
    UNION ALL
      SELECT 'mult' AS tbl_name, question FROM multquestions
)
WHERE question = :question
```

So you practically need just one database query, but get the matched question and the originating table name for it.

But consider what @rurouni88 said; it might make sense to restructure your database scheme, if the tables are otherwise identically structured. At the very least you could create a [`VIEW`](http://search.oracle.com/search/search?group=MySQL&q=VIEW) upon your tables using the UNION approach.

Comment: Ahh, your initial comments didn't make sense to me, because you initially didn't mention encapsulating the UNIONs, but now that that is clear, happy with the solution :)